# kendo ui Typescript this keyword

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, typescript, this

i'm using kendo ui grid with typescript

below is the code for grid with edit event

```
        this.Grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                data: this.Entities,
                batch: true,
                schema: kendoSchema,
                pageSize: 40
            },

            edit: this.editEvent
          }
    private editEvent(e: any): void{
        this.closeCell();
    }
```

grid works fine, problem is, in editEvent "this" keyword is using by kendo (so i dont have access to my class)
and if change it to below "this" will be used by typescript (and i dont have access to kendo)

```
private editEvent = (e: any): void =>{
        this.closeCell();
    }
```

I need my class data to find out witch cell should be readonly, and for that i need kendo.
So, How could I have both functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, How could I have both functionality

Fall back to using an explicit `self` variable.

```
    var self = this;
    this.Grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            data: this.Entities,
            batch: true,
            schema: kendoSchema,
            pageSize: 40
        },

        edit: self.editEvent
    }
```